# Find max/minima of $x\sqrt{16-x^{2}}$

Tags: calculus

This function has a closed interval of (-4, 0), (4, 0), while passing through the origin.

I'm struggling to find the maxima and minima of the function, since this finction doesn't have a standalone constant.  According to my book, f has a relative minimum if f'(x) changes from negative to positive at (c, f(c)), and a relative maximum from positive to negative at (c, f(c)).

I calculated the first derivative as $\sqrt{16-x^{2}} -\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{16-x^{2}}}$ and the critical points are at $x= -4, 0, 4$.  I've been taught that to find the relative max/min by plugging in the critical number(s) into f(x), but in this case, zero is the only output.

One other difficulty I have is these calculations require a number from a given interval.  Other than picking a number at random or testing each possiblilty, how do you find the min/max when there is no constant number in the function?

Comment: Are you sure you've found the correct critical points? I find them to be $x=-4,\pm 2\sqrt{2}, 4$ based on your first derivative.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that was it.  finding the critical points is my weak spot right now.

Comment: Yes, I think that may have been the snag. I've just posted an answer showing how to calculate them in this case. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you have found the incorrect critical points. To find them, you set $f'(x)=0$, in this case,
$$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{16-x^{2}} -\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{16-x^{2}}}=0 &\implies \sqrt{16-x^2}=\frac{x^{2}}{\sqrt{16-x^{2}}} \\
&\implies 16-x^2=x^2 \\
&\implies x^2=8 \\
&\implies x=\pm 2\sqrt{2}
\end{align*}
$$
So your critical points are $x=-4,\pm 2\sqrt{2},4$, when you include the endpoints of your interval. Plugging back in, you find $f(4)=f(-4)=0$, and $f(2\sqrt{2})=8$ and $f(-2\sqrt{2})=-8$. From this you can conclude what the relative extrema are on your interval.

Comment: Thats the part I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\sqrt{16 - x^2}$ is just $y$ in a circle with radius 4, so you're really maximizing the area of a rectangle inscribed in a circle.  What shape would that be?

As far as the calculus goes, I think you took the derivative correctly and messed up with the algebra in finding critical points.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find a critical point of 0? You'd like $f'(x)$ to be 0 or undefined.